# How to create an UItoolbar in SwiftUI with Xcode 11.2

Tags: swift, swiftui

I don't know how to create an `UIToolbar` at the bottom of the screen in SwiftUI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no controller in SwiftUI but you can add like this.

```
var body: some View {  
            NavigationView {  
                VStack {  
                    List(model.items) { item in  
                        ItemViewRow(item: item)  
                    }  
                    HStack {  
                        Button(action: {  
                        }) {  
                            Image(systemName: "someimage")  
                        }  
                        Spacer()  
                        Button(action: {  
                        }) {  
                            Image(systemName: "someimage")  
                        }  
                    }.padding()  
                }  
                .navigationBarTitle(Text("Items"))  
            }  
        }
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: @HoritsuPotter You're Welcome! Please accept my answer. Happy Coding :)